# How to efficiently write a csv file with thousands of columns using csvhelper?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am working on measurement software from which results are written to a huge list of lists which I am trying to put into .csv file using csvhelper. Problem is that to keep things fairly readable and I need to create thousands of columns and I don't see any simple and effective way to do it.

How can I create a .csv file which consist, let's say, 2000 columns?

EDIT 1.
Sorry for my inaccurate post (it was my first ever made on StackOverflow).

Problem I am trying to solve is to create a .csv file with thousands of columns while using only a couple of lines of code so that a program will be as simple as possible. The main reason why I want to do it that way is to keep file readable by different software for data analysis.

Comment: "fairly readable" "simple" and "effective" are all subjective metrics.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about adding properties to an ExpandoObject() (perhaps programatically in a loop) and then writing it out like so:

```
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<dynamic>();

    dynamic record = new ExpandoObject();
    record.Id = 1;
    record.Name = "one";
    records.Add(record);

    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(records);

        writer.ToString().Dump();
    }
}
```

https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/writing/write-dynamic-objects

Comment: I am not sure, but are you certain that the CsvWriter does not buffer data (i.e. is it ensured that it does not keep data unwritten to the underlying writer in an internal buffer until the CsvWriter is disposed of (or flushed)? I guess, a generally more robust approach would be to let the StringWriter dump only after the CsvWriter has been disposed of, thus making sure that the StringWriter got the complete data without relying on implementation details of CsvWriter regarding potential buffering...

Comment: I think the OP was interested in programming efficiency (eg. how to add 2000 columns and keep the code readable), rather than efficiency of saving the file.

Comment: Efficiency != reliability. I was not talking about efficiency, i was talking about reliability. What does it matter how efficiently 2000 columns are being added, when the actual file is not being saved **reliably**...? Hence my question in my first comment whether you are certain about CsvWriter not buffering (are you?)